# Matplotlib subplots where one graph has multiple lines with and one doesn't

Tags: python, matplotlib

currently trying this:

```
fig, ax1, ax3 = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10,5))

# share rate line and ax
ax1.plot(temp_df.index, temp_df['share_rate'], 'b-')
ax1.set_ylim([0,.03])

# % of total video views line and ax
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(temp_df.index, temp_df['percent_of_total_views'], 'r-')

# third plot
ax3.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4])

plt.show()
```

but receiving this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-a8364e1f65f8> in <module>()
     10     print "average share rate: "
     11 
---> 12     fig, ax1, ax3 = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10,5))
     13 
     14     # share rate line and ax

ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

Comment: Change ```fig, ax1, ax3 = plt.subplots(1, 2,figsize=(10,5))``` to ```fig, (ax1, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 2,figsize=(10,5))``` There are only 2 values returned, but you want 3 within your statement. What you really want is: obtaining 2, but unpacking the second.

Comment: @sascha i figured `fig, ax1, ax3 = plt.subplots(1, 2,figsize=(10,5))` would work, but i can't figure out why it isn't

Comment: Read my updated comment above. This is not about matplotlib, but about basic python concepts.

Comment: @sascha that solved my problem.  would you like to add it as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using matplotlibs [subplots-function](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots) in a wrong way.

The statement of yours

```
fig, ax1, ax3 = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10,5))  # WRONG 3 vars on left, 2 are returned
```

expects a tuple of size 3 returned, which are put into `fig, ax1, ax3`.

But the function returns only a tuple of size 2, `fig, ax` where ax can be a single axis, or a sequence of axis-objects (see docs).

If you know, that this ax is a sequence of size 2, you could unpack it directly on the left side with:

```
fig, (ax1, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10,5))  # CORRECT because 2nd return-value unpacked
```